# Подскажите что не так, или может есть другой вариант реализации кода?

Tags: массивы, c++

Задача: упорядочить статический массив (заполненный случайными числами), чтобы в нём чередовались чётные и нечётные элементы, разницу записываем в конец массива. Функции не использовать.

```
const int n = 10;
int ar[n], ch[n], c2 = 0, c = 0, nch[n], k = 0, p = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ar[i] = rand() % 11;
    cout << ar[i] << "\t";
}

cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (ar[i] % 2 == 0) // если четное присваиваем массиву ch
    {
        ch[c] = ar[i];
        c++;
    }
    else
    {
        nch[c2] = ar[i]; // если нечетное массиву nch
        c2++;
    }
}

if (c >= c2) // Если в нечетном цифр больше или поровну
{
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < c2 * 2, j < c2 * 2;
            i += 2, j += 2) // похоже где-то cдесь что-то не то
    {
        ar[i] = ch[k];
        ar[j] = nch[p];
        k++;
        p++;
    }

    for (int i = c2; i < c; i++) // дописываем разницу
    {
        ar[i] = ch[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) // вывод массива
    {
        cout << ar[j] << "\t";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    k = 0;
    p = 0;
}

if (c2 > c)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < c * 2, j < c * 2; i += 2, j += 2)
    {
        ar[i] = ch[k];
        ar[j] = nch[p];
        k++;
        p++;
    }

    for (int i = c; i < c2; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = nch[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << ar[j] << "\t";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Программу запускали? Работает правильно?

Comment: Путаются цифры

Comment: @sasha777, вообще-то достаточно одного вспомогательного массива (размером с исходный). Четные из исходного заносите в его начало, а нечетные в конец (т.е. навстречу друг другу). 

Что-то вроде:

    for (i = 0, odd = 0, even = n-1; i < n; i++)
        if (ar[i] % 2)
            aux[odd++] = ar[i];
        else
            aux[even--] = ar[i];

Вторым проходом переносите их в смежные элементы исходного массива.
Попробуйте, это просто.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Немного странное задание конечно - нельзя использовать функции, но рэндомное число как-то получать нужно...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;
   using std::list;
   using std::vector;
   const int size=10;
   int arr[size];
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       arr[i]=rand()%20;
      // if(rand()%2) arr[i]*=-1;
       cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
   }
   //чет и нечет
   list<int> list_even;
   list<int> list_odd;
   for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
   if(arr[i]%2)        //есть остаток    
       list_even.push_back(arr[i]);       
   else
       list_odd.push_back(arr[i]);

   }
   //
   cout<<"Merging: "<<endl;
   //merge sort
   //alternating numbers
   vector<int> result_mass;
   bool flag=true;

   while(!list_even.empty()||!list_odd.empty()) 
   {
       if(flag){
            if(list_even.empty())
            {       
                result_mass.push_back(list_odd.front());
                list_odd.pop_front();
            }
            else{
                result_mass.push_back(list_even.front());       
                list_even.pop_front();

            }
        flag=false;
       }
       else
       {
           if(list_odd.empty())
           {
               result_mass.push_back(list_even.front());
               list_even.pop_front();

           }
           else{

                result_mass.push_back(list_odd.front());
                list_odd.pop_front();
           }

           flag=true;

       }

   }

   for(vector<int>::const_iterator i=result_mass.begin(); i!=result_mass.end(); i++)
   {
         cout<<*i<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

ЗЫ. Для соединения двух массивов с четными и нечетными числами я бы использовал сортировку слиянием.
Почитай на википедии про стек, структуры данных, и сортировку слиянием.

Comment: Нельзя использовать функции для решения(еще не проходили). А как это сортировка слиянием?

Comment: Знаешь что такое стэк?

Comment: Тебе вообще на чем писать надо, на Си или Си++? Если есть ограничения по памяти то алгоритм усложнится.

Comment: Может тебе надо написать какой-то е*нутый алгоритм сортировки пузырьков который выталкивает попеременно то четные то нечетные эелменты на нужную позицию в массиве...

Comment: Уточни у тичера что именно от тебя требуется, спроси, есть ли ограничения по памяти.

Comment: Ограничения по памяти нет. Надо на C++.Про стек не знаю.